# How to set div width dynamically based on height

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code

```
<div class="persoonal">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="rigth"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS code

```
.profile {
width: 100%;}

.left {
width: 50%;
float: left;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;}

.rigth {
float: right;
width: 48%;
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;}
```

I am new to HTML,

I want to give the left div width 50% when the right div's height is 100px,
and I want to give that same left div width 100% when its height is above 100px.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by jquery,

```
    var div_width = $( ".left" ).width();
var r_div_height = $( ".right" ).height();
if(r_div_height == '100')
    $( ".left" ).width('50');
if(div_width == '100')
    $( ".left" ).width('100');
```

This way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, this might help

```js
if ($('.rigth').height() > 100) {
  $('.left').css("width", "100%");
}
```

```css
.profile {
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.rigth {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="persoonal">
  <div class="left">Test</div>
  <div class="rigth">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```